# End to end transaction view for components integrated using ServiceBus

Tags: azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

```
+-------------------+       +----------------+        +-----------------+
|                   |       |                |        |                 |       +------+
|                   |       |                |        |                 |       |      |
|  Component A      +------->  ServiceBus    <--------+  Component B    +------->  DB  |
|                   |       |                |        |                 |       |      |
|                   |       |                |        |                 |       +------+
+-------------------+       +----------------+        +-----------------+
```

This is simplified version of my system. I would like to be able to see all components in end to end transaction view in Application Insights.

What I currently see is two operations.

1. Component A publishing message two Service Bus
2. Component B receiving message from Service Bus and writing to DB (sql statements included)

Is it possible to achieve this? How can application insights correlate operation in Component A and Component B?

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus messages have a `CorrelationId` property which can be set and the same is expected to be propagated in further messages or processes.

If all of the logs from each component are sent under the same application insights key, you can query for the correlation id and get the logs from different components.

If your components are written in .NET, the [.NET client has auto-tracing available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing#service-bus-net-client-auto-tracing).

Comment: I do set CorrelationId and promote it through my system and I'm able to find all logs from all components. I also add and also promote Diagnostic-Id on ServiceBus message UserProperties level. I hoped that when I go to Failures, or Performance tab in app insights I would be able to see transaction from first component to last. But I'm not. It's like it splits it into smaller transactions. On top of the screen I see list of operation_ids but I have no idea how the tool selects those.